# Variable in debugger doesn't change when it's supposed to, but a created a "watch" of the same value and this one changes

Tags: java, debugging, netbeans

First off, I'm new to the debugger tool  and still consider myself a beginner in programming. My first day of using the debugger and trying to figure stuff out. Anyways, i have a program that works as expected, but while using the debugger to go through step by step, I noticed one of my values doesn't change when it's supposed to, yet the program still goes on correctly as if the value did change. So I restarted the program and created a watch for the same variable. As i'm single-stepping through it, the variable i'm watching changes, but not the value of the same variable the debugger shows automatically.

```
        while (tempNumber < number)
        {
            prime = true;
            for (int i = 2; i < tempNumber; i++)
            {
                remainder = (tempNumber % i);
                if (remainder == 0)
                    prime = false;
            }
            if (prime == true)
                System.out.println(tempNumber);
            tempNumber++;
        }
```

So, form the beginning, tempNumber = 4, number = 10. In the part where it calculates the remainder, "tempNumber % i" is "4 % 2" which is 0. The debugger highlights the part

> prime = false;

and as soon as step into the next line or proceed in the debugger, the **prime** variable in watches changes to **false**, but the **prime** variable the debugger shows automatically, stays as **true**

EDIT: Ok, so i'm not sure what happned, but i went netbeans to screen shot the debugger and maybe the code also, but the prime value in the debugger somehow changed to false while i was writing this question out. I did some retests and now, they both change to false at the same time when it's supposed to. Everything is working as it supposed to now, but i wasted so much time writing this question out, i'm kinda salty and my question now is why this happened in the first place.

[My debugger, I edited to show what it was like before I spent an hour creating this question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPnSW.png)

Comment: Hi, please delete this question as it can not be reproduced

Comment: @Villat In case you were not aware, you can vote to close this question for the reason _"This question was caused by **a problem that can no longer be reproduced**..."_.

Comment: Since you cannot specify how to reproduce the original problem, it is very unlikely that anyone will be able to assist you, so you are very unlikely to get an answer on _"why this happened in the first place"_.

Comment: Hey @skomisa I knew about that, but I didn't have remaining flags.

Comment: @Villat would you happen to know how i can delete this question, i can't seem to find it.